# Windows form design not updated when running?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using VS2012(c# winforms w/ devexpress).
I added a Ribbon Control and tried to debug the project.
I have noticed the form doesn't have a Ribbon Control.
I tried deleting the bin folder, but that did not helped.

Comment: Added...how? Where? At run-time? Of course it won't show in designer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Delete the bin folder and the rebuild the project. 
Step 2. If step 1 doesn't work check the visibility property of your ribbon control maybe it is set to `false`

Comment: Thanks! After deleting the bin folder i tried restarting my machine and it worked!